# Interpreting a new line in string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, textbox

**Context:**
I'm making a Simon Says game, but unlike normal Simon Says games (where random sequences are generated each time), I wish to make the sequences non-random and based on `textbox1.text` due to the nature of the game. So for example: `textbox1.text` may include the line "RYRG". Which the game interprets as "Red, Yellow, Red, Green".

**Question:**
With the help of a really helpful user, I've managed to write some code that reads exactly this and interprets it as a sequence. We used Dictionary for matching the char to Color, but sadly this only works for one line (e.g. "RGGB"). Please could you look at the code below.
How can I make it read more than one line (so that the program interprets it as: next line = next sequence)? For example:

input string textBox1.Text =

```
RGYR
RGGB
RGRG
RYBG
RYYB
GBRY
RYBG
```

Code:

```
private Color[] sequence;
//Declare dictionary
private Dictionary<char,Color>  stringTocolor = new Dictionary<char,Color>();

public SimonSays ()
{
    //add content to Dictionary
    stringTocolor.Add('R', Color.Red);
    stringTocolor.Add('G', Color.Green);
    stringTocolor.Add('B', Color.Blue);
    stringTocolor.Add('Y', Color.Yellow);

    Color[] colourset = newSequence(textBox1.Text.Length);
}

public Color[] newSequence(int length)
{
    Color[] array = new Color[length];
    //check dictionary has the char key or not
    for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (stringTocolor.ContainsKey(textBox1.Text[i]))
        {
             array[i] = stringTocolor[textBox1.Text[i]];
        }
        //give alert if wrong key
        else
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Wrong Colour input at index " + i + " of textbox string!");
        }
    }
    this.sequence = array;
    return array;
}

    public void newSequence (Color [] sequence)
    {
        this.sequence=sequence;

    }
```

Comment: so where do you want to store the next sequence(s) ?

Comment: Hi Selman22, thanks for the message. 

  `public void newSequence (Color [] sequence)
  {
   this.sequence=sequence;
            
  }`

Comment: Do you understand my question ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't understand it. Let's just store it in textbox2. I hope I got what you mean...

Comment: When you use this method with `RGBY BYGR` you should get eight values in your Color array, right ? the newline doesn't matter because it just skips the if statement.So, my question is, where do you want to store the next sequence ? for example if there are three lines it should be three sequences according to your question right ?

Comment: Ahh yes, it's in an array. So  3 lines means 3 sequences, with 12 values in the Color array.

Comment: @user3403843 ignoring the newline enables you to look at the string as one part (not 3 parts), so your code can easily do it's job by ignoring the newline(s).

Comment: Thanks Mahdi, that makes sense. If it means anything, I get errors on index 47,52,53,58,59,64,65, etc
It's going up by 1, and 5. So if I look at the string as one line, I think I have to think about doing something with that 1 and 5...

Comment: @user3403843 take a look at my answer, using the code I have given you should not encounter errors, test my code and let me know if you still had problems.

Comment: Hi Mahdi! Thanks for the answer, I tested it out. It says 'index was outside the bounds of the array in the error'. 

It should be one line per index, I think.

Comment: @user3403843 welcome. What is the input string you are testing?

Comment: Hi Mahdi, I updated the question just now with the input string. I can't format it correctly in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to ignore the new line characters **\r\n**

```
string puretext = textBox1.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""); //Ignore newline(s)
for (int i = 0; i < puretext.Length; i++)
{
    if (stringTocolor.ContainsKey(puretext[i]))
    {
         array[i] = stringTocolor[puretext[i]];
    }
    //give alert if wrong key
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Wrong Colour input at index " + i + " of textbox string!");
    }
}
```

Comment: that is not the problem.and this won't compile because `textBox1.Text[i]` is a _char_ and `Environment.Newline` is _string_.

Comment: I'm on mobile phone, let me start up my laptop and I'll correct the code in a minute...